# SQLite/FoxPro Update can't find record using = but finds it using LIKE

Tags: sqlite, visual-foxpro

I'm converting a FoxPro database to SQLite, and migrating the instructions to update, where I found a problem.

If inside FoxPro I use `Update Fact01 set Motivo = 'asdfgh' where TipoDoc='FV'`
the rows are not updated.

But if I use `Update Fact01 set Motivo = 'asdfgh' where TipoDoc Like 'FV'` the rows are changed.

If I do the first instruction inside the SQLite engine, the rows are also changed. The field type for TipoDoc is NChar(2).

Also, If i do a `select * from Fact01 where TipoDoc ='FV'` statement inside Foxpro it works OK.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT typeof(TipoDoc), hex(TipoDoc) FROM Fact01 WHERE TipoDoc LIKE 'FV'`?

Comment: @CL. the output of typeof(TipoDoc) is Text, while the Hex returns 4656

Comment: Wait, the problem happens in FoxPro? Then why do you have "SQLite" in the title?

Comment: @CL. Sorry, updated the title

Comment: VFP do not have an nchar nor text data type. It is not clear if you are running the query against a VFP table or SQLite table via ODBC driver. Basic difference between = and Like is the latter is ANSI. What happens if you use set ansi on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's due to the fact that Nchar can store unicode data or the way data in general is stored. Wrapping an ALLTRIM around the WHERE clause may correct the problem.

```
Update Fact01 set Motivo = 'asdfgh' where ALLTRIM(TipoDoc)='FV'
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because i stored the column value as a BLOB instead of TEXT. Turns out the BLOB value is less than a TEXT value so LIKE found matches but = did not. you might be having the same issue.

Comment: As I said, the column in SQLite is a NChar, and the result in FoxPro (as mentioned in the comments above) is a Text...